# MySQL FIND_IN_SET() not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
... | parents_id   | ...
________________________
... | 1, 40, 7     | ...
... | 10, 4, 7, 1  | ...
... | 45, 40, 1, 7 | ...
... | other_rows   | ...
```

Now, I need to get these three rows, I use this query `SELECT * FROM products WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, parents_id) > 0`, but I only get the first row (`1, 40, 7`), any help?

Comment: I guess its the spaces, please try removing the spaces post comma-separator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[As per documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) - `FIND_IN_SET`'s second argument is a comma separated list. So the value `10, 4, 7, 1` being split by a comma becomes to the following 4 values:

1. `10`
2. `4` - space followed by 4
3. `7` - space followed by 7
4. `1` - space followed by 1

None of them equal to `1`

Solution: stop using this approach and normalize your schema to use one-to-many (or many-to-many).

Comment: Thank you so much! Putting leading space works for me. But I'll remove it after. :)

Comment: @zerkms is it possible to use for space value in  FIND_IN_SET , for exampl I have a couln value " Architecture and Engineering Services, Services " . Here how I like to use like this WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Architecture and Engineering Services', COULMN_NAME)

Comment: @GnanasekaranLoganathan it's possible and that whole value (the complete string of 4 words and 3 spaces) will be looked for.

Comment: Sorry I did not get it. when I tried this FIND_IN_SET('Architecture and Engineering Services', COULMN_NAME), not getting this " Architecture and Engineering Services, Services " row

Comment: Because `'Architecture and Engineering Services'` string is not equal to `" Architecture and Engineering Services"`. Have you checked the documentation on that function?

Comment: Yes, I checked.  " This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (,) character. "  So space and comma treated equally in query !?

Comment: @GnanasekaranLoganathan space has no special meaning for `FIND_IN_SET`. Please have documentation another chance: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set In your example there is no comma in the first argument.